# Receiving Run time error 91 on only some Win 10 machines here

Tags: excel, vba

This is a weird error.  It only occurs on some machines here, but not all of them. Furthermore, I researched this website and there are no solutions that I can see that cover this.

I receive this error when attempting to run some VBA code in an excel document.

The line of code it occurs in is in the

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

event.

The line of code is:

```
Set objTest = CreateObject("MTRClassLibrary.MTRTestComClass")
```

As I mentioned previously, the code only errors out on some of the machines here but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear where and how the `objTest` instance is declared in the code. Also, you need to make sure the corresponding object is registered on the problematic machine. The `CreateObject` can't locate applications with `ProgId` passed as a parameter. Try to check the Windows registry for the string passed.

See [Object variable not set (Error 91)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91) for all possible cases.

Comment: How do I check the Windows registry?

Comment: Try to search for the string passed to the `CreatedObject` method.

Comment: i checked the windows registry and the string is there in the registry.

Comment: I'd suggest posting the full sub code here, so we could see everything else is done correctly.

Comment: to clarify, this isn't my code .. I took over for someone else who wrote this and is no longer with the company.